Domain trust failed | The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted
We have this VM server in office. It gives the error "the trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed" on login. This is fixed by a restart of the client, but always comes back within 24-48 hours.
We re-establish the domain on laptop or sometimes restart the server to get it fixed. But We need a constant solution for this.
Any ideas on how to prevent this from constantly occurring?
We tried resetting the session timer and rejoined domain multiple times.
We have also turned the firewall off.

Try resetting the computer account in active directory and then rejoin the domain. Also, ensure that time synchronization between the VM and domain controller is consistent to prevent trust issues.
